# Laravel redirect to home page

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Language switch to switch between English and Arabic. It is working fine in all the links except Home page.

1. If I have not authenticated it is working fine it is redirecting to `http://domain.name/en/login`
2. If I have authenticated or logged in and try to access the url `http://domain.name/` it is redirecting to `http://domain.name/home` instead of a `http://domain.name/en/home`

I have changed in all the Auth files by adding a function:

```
public function redirectTo(){
    return app()->getLocale().'/home';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to make a automatic redirect to the page.

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});
```